# Probability , boxes

Tags: probability

Two boxes A and B, box A contains $3$ black counters and $2$ White counters , box B contains 2 black counters and 1 white counter , Farah takes at random a counter from A ,then puts it into B , then she takes a counter at random from B .
Find the probability that : the ball taken from B will be black ?

Comment: Are balls and counters the same thing? Also, please detail what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3/5 chance that a black is added to box B, and then a 3/4 chance a black is chosen from box B. There is also a 2/5 chance a white is added to box B and then a 2/4 chance a black is chosen from box B. These two scenarios are exclusive, so the overall prob a black is chosen from box B is $$\frac{3}{5}\ \frac{3}{4}+\frac{2}{5}\ \frac{2}{4}=\frac{13}{20}$$

----- Added later

To be more formal, let $T$ be the event that a black is added to box B, and $E$ the event that a black is chosen from box B. We want $p(E)$. We have $$p(E)=p(E|T)p(T)+p(E|\text{not} T)p(\text{not} T)$$ $$=\frac{3}{4}\ \frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{4}\ \frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Would you illustrate why did you multiply the probabilities in the two cases ? in other words how can i know that question needs multiplication of probabilities ?@almagest

Comment: @HussienMohamed Does the addition above help?

Comment: Yes , thank you too much